# How to create a chart with EPPlus with multiple series?

Tags: c#, excel, charts, epplus

I'm trying to create this chart using EPPlus:

```
Area            Imports         Exports
North America   9.00010837      14.54751448
South America   7.878137347     4.878011063
Europe          32.41924303     39.37317481
Middle East     6.859031587     12.94288951
Africa          7.611513341     2.938054884
Asia            36.23196633     25.32035526
```

The result should look like:

[image: Excel Column clustered chart]

Here's my code:

```
dataSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Area";
dataSheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Imports";
dataSheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "Exports";

var row = 2;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    dataSheet.Cells["A" + row].Value = item.GeographicalAreaPersianName;
    dataSheet.Cells["B" + row].Value = item.ImportsShare;
    dataSheet.Cells["C" + row].Value = item.ExportsShare;
    row++;
}


var diagram = diagramSheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart", eChartType.ColumnClustered);

for (int i = 2; i <= row; i++)
{
    var series = diagram.Series.Add($"'Data'!B{i}:C{i}", $"'Data'!A{i}:A{i}");
}
diagram.Border.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```

Yet what I get is this result:

[image: Excel Column clustered chart]

As you can see series title is not shown correctly and I can't find proper help in EPPlus. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us say that data are stored as demonstrated by the following screenshot:

[image: excel data]

The following should do the trick:

```
var diagram = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart", eChartType.ColumnClustered);

for (int i = 2; i <= row; i++)
 {
  var series = diagram.Series.Add($"B{i}:C{i}", "B1:C1");
  series.Header = worksheet.Cells[$"A{i}"].Value.ToString();
 }
diagram.Border.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```

The second parameter of Add method stands for title of series {"Imports", "Exports"}

For the Areas, you have to set the header.

Resulting chart looks like: (Actual result of code above):

[image: excel column clustered chart]