# EPPlus WaterFall chart type

Tags: c#, .net, epplus, waterfall

I'm using the **EPPlus** library to read/write Excel files: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

I would like to draw a Water Fall Chart and I am wondering what is the right type to be used.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056329/how-to-create-a-chart-with-epplus-with-multiple-series

Comment: @DanielBlais thank you, but I am looking for WaterFall chart

Comment: Sorry.....
But I beleive Waterfall chart is "Column Stacked" chart type.
`OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.eChartType.ColumnStacked`

Comment: @DanielBlais Ok, you mean to create a ColumnStacked Chart and later make some series invisible.

Comment: I found the trick here.  https://chandoo.org/wp/excel-waterfall-charts/  There are others links as well on google.